# Assimp loader with a cube of 8 vertices

Tags: opengl, blender, assimp

I'm loading a .obj model of a cube currently using those flags :

```
const aiScene* scene = importer.ReadFile(path, aiProcess_Triangulate | aiProcess_FlipUVs | aiProcess_GenNormals | aiProcess_JoinIdenticalVertices);
```

The model only contains 8 vertices (each sommet of the cube) and thus no duplicate vertices to specify assimp to draw all of the triangles needed. 
As a result, I only get 3 triangles of my box drawn.

I believe this is because I use :

```
glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, vertices.size());
```

Where vertices.size() is equal to 22 (it's the return of mesh->mNumVertices).

I don't get this 22, to me it should either be 8 or 6*2*3 = 36 (6 faces with 2 triangles each). Can anyone explain where it comes from ?

I though of using GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP but the vertices are not in the right order (I don't even know if they can be). I get more triangles but not the right ones.

So my main question is : is there a flag I could add to ReadFile -or something else- to write a copy of the vertices for each triangle to be drawn in the .obj file.

PS : I exported the Wavefront model from Blender, maybe it's on Blender that I can set something to export redondant vertices.

My .obj file : 
      o 1

```
  # Vertex list

  v -0.5 -0.5 0.5
  v -0.5 -0.5 -0.5
  v -0.5 0.5 -0.5
  v -0.5 0.5 0.5
  v 0.5 -0.5 0.5
  v 0.5 -0.5 -0.5
  v 0.5 0.5 -0.5
  v 0.5 0.5 0.5

  usemtl Default
  f 4 3 2 1
  f 2 6 5 1
  f 3 7 6 2
  f 8 7 3 4
  f 5 8 4 1
  f 6 7 8 5
```

EDIT : How I set up the mesh with Qt OpenGL types (and now with EBO):

```
   void setupMesh(QOpenGLShaderProgram* program)
    {
    // Create Vertex Array Object
    if (!VAO->isCreated()) {
        VAO->create();
    }
    VAO->bind();

    VBO.create();
    VBO.bind();

    VBO.setUsagePattern(QOpenGLBuffer::StaticDraw);

    construct_sg_vertex();

    VBO.allocate(this->m_vec.constData(), this->m_vec.size() * sizeof(m_vec.at(0)));


    EBO.create();
    EBO.bind(); //glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, ebo);
    EBO.setUsagePattern(QOpenGLBuffer::StaticDraw);
    EBO.allocate(indices.data(),indices.size()*sizeof(GLuint)); 

    // 0 : positions
    program->enableAttributeArray(0);
    program->setAttributeBuffer(0, GL_FLOAT, Vertex::positionOffset(), Vertex::PositionTupleSize, Vertex::stride());

    //1: colors
    program->enableAttributeArray(1);
    program->setAttributeBuffer(1, GL_FLOAT, Vertex::colorOffset(), Vertex::ColorTupleSize, Vertex::stride());

    VBO.release();
    EBO.release();
}

private:

QOpenGLBuffer VBO ;
QOpenGLVertexArrayObject* VAO = new QOpenGLVertexArrayObject();
QOpenGLBuffer EBO ; //New Element Buffer
};
```

With this added indices buffer I changed the way I draw to : 
       VAO->bind() ; 
       glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, indices.size(),GL_UNSIGNED_INT,0);

As a result, nothing is rendered at all...

Comment: You are leaving out some essential information here, e.g how do you setup your buffer (glBindBuffer, glEnableVertexAttribArray, glVertexAttribPointer).
What does your .obj look like? Is backface culling enabled?

Comment: Backface culling is enabled. 
I'm using Qt for shaders and VAO actually. I'm editing so that you can see how I set them up.

Comment: Only taking the vertices into account is not enough. You also need the faces to know how the vertices are assembled.

Comment: Yes but the f x  y z t does the assembling in the obj file I believe, doesn't it ?

Comment: Yes, this line is for assembly. But you don't take that into account. This information is stored in `mFaces`. You have to build a index buffer from that.

Comment: Ok but if I build and index buffer and then use glDrawElements() to render my model, I believe this code won't work anymode for my main model which is not the cube but a drone that is renderer fine now and does not include faces. 

I'm saying that because at first I used an index buffer and then had to delete this step.

Comment: What do you mean by: "Does not include faces?" When the obj file does not have face information, then it is simply incomplete. Nevertheless, for this example you will need an index buffer.

Comment: When you call `EBO.release()` before unbinding the vao, the index buffer binding gets removed from the vao.

Comment: Ok I deleted EBO but still no result. I don't get it because my indices vector is filled with 36 good values, so is my vertices vector that is filled with relevant Vertex_Struct values (only position and color for now). 

Is there a debug method I could use to catch what I'm doing wrong ?

Answer (score 1):

From the flags you provide I would expect 24 vertices to be generated: A cube consists of 6 faces, each composed of 2 triangles. When now normals are generated (as requested by `aiProcess_GenNormals`), each side of the cube has 4 unique vertices. Note, that vertex refers here to a combination of position and normal. 4 unique vertices and six sides are in total 24 vertices.

Now to the drawing problem: Since `aiProcess_JoinIdenticalVertices` is request, assimp will join together all identical vertices, leaving  only these unique vertices in the `aiMesh->mVertices` array. Alone, this information is not sufficient to draw anything. What is needed in addition, is the information about how these vertices have to be assembled in triangles, which is given by `aiMesh->mFaces`. From these faces, one either has to generate an index buffer, or assembly the vertices into a new array by duplicating them in the correct order. The next code shows how the data for the index buffer can be constructed:

```
std::vector<unsigned int> indices;
indices.reserve(aimesh->mNumFaces * 3);
for (unsigned int fid = 0; fid < aimesh->mNumFaces; fid++)
{
    auto& face = aimesh->mFaces[fid];
    for (size_t iid = 0; iid < 3; iid++)
        indices.push_back(face.mIndices[iid]);
}
```

The indices data can than be used by OpenGL.